# grunt-contrib-qunit plugin is looking for qunit.js file along with my tests.html

Tags: gruntjs, phantomjs, qunit, grunt-contrib-qunit

I tried loading qunit js from both tests.html and through require, but irrespective of how I load qunit, when I run grunt task to run qunit tests it is failing tests with timeout and in the error it states qunit.js is not found in the same folder where my tests.html is present. I am able to overcome this issue by simply copying the qunit.js file. I don't want to keep qunit.js in this additional location, can you please share your thoughts why it is looking for qunit.js at this specific location.

Thanks
Sudhakar

Comment: We'll need to see your qunit task config, and possibly your `tests.html` file.

Comment: tests.html has typical qunit html content, the css and other fixtures. Qunit task is as follows: qunit: {            
            all: ['tests/tests.html']
        }

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment... if you can't show us the full config and test file we can't help you. Saying it has "typical qunit content" doesn't help because we don't know your level of experience with qunit. Did you remember to include everything? We don't know... that's why we need to see your code. Otherwise we can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue while setting up the QUnit workflow for my AMD Oracle JET project.

The reason for this seems to be the absence of the 'qunit' path in the requirejs configuration.

Adding this:

```
require.config({
    ...    
    paths: {
        'qunit': 'path/to/your/qunit/js'
    }
})
```

...and moving all the code in my data-main file to a `<script></script>` block within the `<body>` of `index.html` did the trick for me.

Hope this helps.